# UrlHelper returning http links on Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, azure-web-app-service, urlhelper

I have a service that when deployed on Azure App Services returns `http` links instead of `https` links when using `UrlHelper`. When testing on my development machine it returns `https` links as expected, and the service is available and accessed through `https` requests.

An example of the type of route from my startup I'm trying to use is:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    "FooBar",
    "api/Foo/{Id}/Bar");
```

The link is then constructed using:

```cs
IUrlHelper _urlHelper = // Injected into class via service registration
int id = 42; // Arbitrary value for example
_urlHelper.Link("FooBar", new {Id = id});
```

When running on my local machine using Docker on Windows from Visual Studio I get a link of `https://localhost:1234/api/Foo/42/Bar`, but on my deployed Linux Container App Service on Azure I get `http://my-app-name.azurewebsites.net/api/Foo/42/Bar`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong to get an `http` link instead of an `https` link, and would appreciate any advice/pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution was with the configuration of the ASP.Net Core app itself. I performed the following modifications and then everything worked correctly:

Added `app.UseForwardedHeaders();` to the request pipeline.

Added the following snippet to service container registration:

```cs
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All;
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
```

The `KnownNetworks` and `KnownProxies` need to be cleared as they default to assuming an IIS hosting environment. For extra security you can add the known proxy/network IPs instead of clearing them here.